# Resetting an array of numbers by repeated subtraction from a sub-array

Tags: algorithm, math, optimization, structure, sub-array

There is an array of numbers between 0 and 6 (base 7). For example {0 4 6 2 2 0 3 1}. Its maximum length can be 501 elements.
Each step we can subtract a number from any number of elements. All of the elements must be adjacent (form a continuous sub-array). The number subtracted from all of the elements must be the same.

If an element (let's call it A) after subtraction doesn't fit in the range of 0 to 6, then A becomes A modulo 7. For example after subtracting 3 from the whole array `{0 4 6 2 2 0 3 1}`, we would get
`{4 1 3 6 6 4 0 5}`.

The task is to find the smallest amount of steps necessary to get an array with just zeros.

For example for the array `{0 4 6 2 2 0 3 1}` it would take 4 steps:

`{0 4 6 2 2 0 3 1}` subtract 2 from elements with indexes 2-4

`{0 4 4 0 0 0 3 1}` subtract 4 from elements with indexes 1 and 2

`{0 0 0 0 0 0 3 1}` subtract 3 from the second to last element

`{0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1}` subtract 1 from the last element

`{0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0}`

First of all finding the solution using brute force is not possible, as for an array of 501 numbers
there are 126 505 506 possible first steps.
(6x(1x501 + 2x500 + 3x499 + 4x498 +...+ 501x1) = 6x21084251 = 126505506).
There would be a lot more possibilities if we include the steps following the first one.

I noticed we can remove an element if it has the same number next to it.
So the array `{0 4 6 2 2 0 3 1}` becomes `{0 4 6 2 0 3 1}`. This should simplify the problem.

I've tried dividing the array into sections using zeros as the dividers.
So for the array `{0 4 6 2 0 3 1}` we could consider two separate arrays: `{4 6 2}` and `{3 1}`.
I thought I could find the answers for those arrays and add them together for the final answer.
But I discovered arrays for which this approach doesn't work.
For example, for the array `{3 2 1 0 1 2 3}` this approach would yield the answer 3 + 3 = 6 while it should be 4 steps:

`{3 2 1 0 1 2 3}` subtract 3 from the whole array

`{0 6 5 4 5 6 0}`subtract 6 for indexes 1 to 5

`{0 0 6 5 6 0 0}` subtract 6 for indexes 2 to 4

`{0 0 0 6 0 0 0}` subtract 6 from the middle element

`{0 0 0 0 0 0 0}`

Another approach I tried was looking for pairs of the same number and dividing the array accordingly.
For example the array: `{0 3 1 5 3 5 6 2 1 5 1}`
would divide into three arrays `{3 1 5 3}` and `{5 6 2 1 5}` and `{6}`.

This would allow me to shorten a sub-array by two elements in just one step:

`{3 1 5 3} {5 6 2 1 5} {6}` subtract from the first subarray

`{0 5 2 0} {5 6 2 1 5} {6}` subtract from the second subarray

`{0 5 2 0} {0 1 4 3 0} {6}` remove zeroes on the sides ->   `{5 2} {1 4 3} {6}`

But I couldn't find a final solution using this approach. Also I don't know how to check whether it always would return the best answer.

Comment: This is a great question! In the second approach, you can make a greedy algorithm by looking for complement *differences* instead of identical numbers. This is probably not enought for optimality, as the order of removals is likely to matter